# Java specification select query

Tags: java

I have a following sql query, that I need to change to java specification:

```
select * from student s where s.group_id in (
select student_id from class c where c.place='23' and c.student_id IS NOT NULL)
or s.tab_num = '23';
```

Here I have two different tables: Student and Class. Here what I have done by now.

```
public static Predicate studentPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<?> r) {

CriteriaQuery<Class> subQuery = cb.createQuery(Class.class);

Root<Class> subRoot = subQuery.from(Class.class);

subQuery.select(subRoot.get("student_id")).where(cb.equal(subRoot.get("place"), 23L), cb.isNotNull(subRoot.get("student_id"));

CriteriaQuery<Dictionary> id = outerQuery.where(outerRoot.get("group_id").in(subQuery));

return cb.or(cb.equal(r.get("tabNum"), 23)); // here is an issue
```

}

I have an issue with the last line of code. Cant compare the id result with cb.or(). Is there a way to resolve this or another way to code the sql query?

Comment: `cb.or(cb.equal(r.get("tabNum"), 23), outerRoot.get("group_id").in(subQuery))`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Predicate studentPredicate(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<Student> root) {
    Subquery<String> subQuery = outerQuery.subquery(String.class);
    Root<Class> subRoot = subQuery.from(Class.class);
    subQuery.select(subRoot.get("student_id"))
            .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get("place"), "23"), criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(subRoot.get("student_id")));
    Predicate mainQueryPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(
            criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("group_id")).value(subQuery),
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("tabNum"), "23")
    );

    return mainQueryPredicate;
}
```

In this code, I have used Subquery instead of CriteriaQuery to retrieve the student IDs from the Class table. The outerQuery.subquery(String.class) gives the type  of the subquery as String (assuming student_id is of type String).

Also i created the mainQueryPredicate using criteriaBuilder.or to group together the two conditions: the IN condition using criteriaBuilder.in with the subquery as the value, the equality condition using criteriaBuilder.equal comparing tabNum with the value "23".

Please adjust the types and conditions according to your data model.